# How to swipe Left to Right in Appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

Since swipe() is deprecated, I am unable to swipe the screen from Left to Right. My App has 4 banners in it and I want to swipe to view all the banners.

Comment: Use touchactions

Answer (score 8):

This applies in all directions:

enum:

```
public enum DIRECTION {
    DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT;
}
```

actual code:

```
public static void swipe(MobileDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    int startX = 0;
    int endX = 0;
    int startY = 0;
    int endY = 0;

    switch (direction) {
        case RIGHT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;

        case LEFT:
            startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
            startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
            endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(endX, startY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

        case UP:
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(startX, endY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();
            break;


        case DOWN:
            startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
            endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
            startX = (size.width / 2);
            new TouchAction(driver)
                    .press(startX, startY)
                    .waitAction(Duration.ofMillis(duration))
                    .moveTo(startX, endY)
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            break;

    }
}
```

usage:

```
swipe(driver,DIRECTION.RIGHT);
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Haven't tested it yet but looks like UP and Down are not quite correct

Comment: For the latest Appium java client API, the TouchAction.press() method takes only PointerOption and not ints. If you face an issue there, check the answer by @Harjeet. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

try below method. It works with Appium 1.16.0 version. 
I created this method to swipe left or right based on a particular element location on the screen. It takes 3 parameters
Element X: It is the X coordinate of the element on which swipe touch action needs to be performed.
Element Y: It is the Y coordinate of the element.
Direction: Left/Right

```
    //method to left and right swipe on the screen based on coordinates
public void swipeAction(int Xcoordinate, int Ycoordinate, String direction) {
    //get device width and height
    Dimension dimension = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int deviceHeight = dimension.getHeight();
    int deviceWidth = dimension.getWidth();
    System.out.println("Height x Width of device is: " + deviceHeight + " x " + deviceWidth);

    switch (direction) {
        case "Left":
            System.out.println("Swipe Right to Left");
            //define starting and ending X and Y coordinates
            int startX=deviceWidth - Xcoordinate;
            int startY=Ycoordinate; // (int) (height * 0.2);
            int endX=Xcoordinate;
            int endY=Ycoordinate;
            //perform swipe from right to left
            new TouchAction((AppiumDriver) driver).longPress(PointOption.point(startX, startY)).moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY)).release().perform();
            break;

        case "Right":
            System.out.println("Swipe Left to Right");
            //define starting X and Y coordinates
            startX=Xcoordinate;
            startY=Ycoordinate;
            endX=deviceWidth - Xcoordinate;
            endY=Ycoordinate;
            //perform swipe from left to right
            new TouchAction((AppiumDriver) driver).longPress(PointOption.point(startX, startY)).moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY)).release().perform();
            break;
    }
}
```

To fetch the element X,Y coordinates. try below methods

```
int elementX= driver.findElement(elementLocator).getLocation().getX();
int elementY= driver.findElement(elementLocator).getLocation().getY();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created  `driver` instance of `AndroidDriver` you can swipe left:

```
    // Get location of element you want to swipe
    WebElement banner = driver.findElement(<your_locator>);
    Point bannerPoint = banner.getLocation();
    // Get size of device screen
    Dimension screenSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    // Get start and end coordinates for horizontal swipe
    int startX = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(screenSize.getWidth() * 0.8));
    int endX = 0;

    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
    action
            .press(PointOption.point(startX, bannerPoint.getY()))
            .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
            .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, bannerPoint.getY()))
            .release();
    driver.performTouchAction(action);
```

Use latest [appium-java-client 6.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0) and Appium 1.8.x server

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
 Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
           System.out.println(size.height+"height");
           System.out.println(size.width+"width");
            System.out.println(size);
            int startPoint = (int) (size.width * 0.99);
            int endPoint = (int) (size.width * 0.15);
            int ScreenPlace =(int) (size.height*0.40);          
            int y=(int)size.height*20;

           TouchAction ts = new TouchAction(driver);
           //for(int i=0;i<=3;i++) {
           ts.press(PointOption.point(startPoint,ScreenPlace ))
          .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(1000)))
          .moveTo(PointOption.point(endPoint,ScreenPlace )).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for iOS Mobile:

```html
//Here i am trying to swipe list of images from right to left 
//First i am getting parent element (table/cell)  id
//Then using predicatestring am searching for the element present or not then trying to click

List<MobileElement> ele = getMobileElement(listBtnQuickLink).findElements(By.xpath(".//XCUIElementTypeButton"));
  
  for(int i=1 ;i<=20;i++) {
   MobileElement ele1 = ele.get(i);
   
   String parentID = getMobileElement(listBtnQuickLink).getId();
   HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
   scrollObject.put("element", parentID); //This is parent element id (not same element)
    
   scrollObject.put("predicateString", "label == '"+ele1.getText()+"'");
   scrollObject.put("direction", "left");
   driver.executeScript("mobile:swipe", scrollObject);  // scroll to the target element
    
   System.out.println("Element is visible : "+ele1.isDisplayed());
   
 
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately i was noted that TouchAction doesn't work on Android 11 with Selenium 4. So if you use Selenide and Appium you can try this:

```
public class SwipeToLeft implements Command<SelenideElement> {
@Nullable
@Override
public SelenideElement execute(SelenideElement proxy, WebElementSource locator, @Nullable Object[] args) throws IOException {
    Selenide.sleep(2000);
    var driver = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver();
    var element = proxy.getWrappedElement();
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("mobile: swipeGesture", ImmutableMap.of(
            "elementId", ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId(),
            "direction", "left",
            "percent", 0.75
    ));
    return proxy;
}
```

}

And then you can use:

```
$('your seleniumLocator').shouldBe(visible).execute(new SwipeToLeft());
```